# How to Access Flask Config File Using Application Factory Pattern?

Tags: python, flask

I'm very confused as to how to access the config file after setting the correct environment in the app blueprint. I'm getting this error:

```
RuntimeError: Working outside of application context.
```

Here's my config file:

```
import os

basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

class Config:
    SECRET_KEY = os.getenv('SECRET_KEY', 'admin123!')
    DEBUG = False

class DevelopmentConfig(Config):
    DEBUG = True
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'sqlite:///' + os.path.join(basedir, 'app.db')
    MLFLOW_TRACKING_URI = <url>
    GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS = 'daodl_access.json'
    SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS = False

class TestingConfig(Config):
    DEBUG = True
    TESTING = True
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'sqlite:///' + os.path.join(basedir, 'app.db')
    MLFLOW_TRACKING_URI = <url>
    GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS = 'daodl_access.json'
    PRESERVE_CONTEXT_ON_EXCEPTION = False
    SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS = False

class ProductionConfig(Config):
    DEBUG = False
    is_prod = os.environ.get('DB_NAME')
    if is_prod:
        SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'postgresql+psycopg2://{user}:{password}@{localhost}/{database}'.format(
            user=os.environ['DB_USER'], password=os.environ['DB_PASS'],
            localhost='127.0.0.1:5432', database=os.environ['DB_NAME'])

    else:
        SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'sqlite:///' + os.path.join(basedir, 'app.db')
    MLFLOW_TRACKING_URI = <url>
    GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS = 'prod_key.json'
    SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS = False

config_by_name = dict(
    dev=DevelopmentConfig,
    test=TestingConfig,
    prod=ProductionConfig
)

key = Config.SECRET_KEY
```

And in a separate python file, I would like to retrieve the config options corresponding to the designated environment I set up when I create the app

```
from flask import current_app
mlflow_tracking_uri = current_app.config['MLFLOW_TRACKING_URI']
os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = current_app.config['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `current_app` or `g` can only access the app within the context of receiving a request, as indicated in the [documentation](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/appcontext/).

> The application context keeps track of the application-level data **during a request**, CLI command, or other activity. Rather than passing the application around to each function, the current_app and g proxies are accessed instead.

Since you are setting the os environment variable, you can do this during the setup of your app. Like so:

```py
import os

from flask import Flask

from .config import config_by_name


def new_app():
    env = os.getenv("ENV", "prod")
    config = config_by_name[env]

    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(config)

    setup_gcp_vars(app)
    return app

# You may also have this function in a
# separate module, then import it into
# the module that sets up your flask app
def setup_gcp_vars(app):
    os.environ["APP_ENV"] = app.config["OS_ENV"]
    mlflow_tracking_uri = app.config['MLFLOW_TRACKING_URI']


app = new_app()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```